# TCP error code 10060:A connection attemp failed bcos the connection party didnot properly respnod after period of time, or established connection fail

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

We have a Framework 4.x WCF Service which is in turn hosted in a Windows Service using Net.Tcp Binding. When calling WCF service from client machine run properly. If we turn on Window firewall then it gives error as

```
****"Error 10060 - Could not connect to net.tcp://1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9098/MyService/. 
The connection attemp lasted for a time span of 00:00:21. TCP error code 10060: A connection attemp failed because the connection party didnot properly respnod after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 19x.xxx.xxx.xxx:9098."****
```

I open port 9098 with Inbound and Outbound rule on machine where WCF service is hosted. And also open 808 port from client machine. Still we get this error.

Comment: Can you "telnet 192x.xxx.xxx.xxx 9098" ?

Comment: @Crowcoder - can you explain in detail?

Comment: If you run that command at a console and it does not come back with something like "...machine actively refused..." then you know the port is open and you can hhit it.

Comment: I execute command "telnet 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9098" - but it gives error as Connecting To 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9098...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: Do as I showed. There is a space after the IP address and no colon in a telnet command.

Comment: I do as you showed 
C:telnet 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9098
but gives error as
Connecting To 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...Could not open connection to the host, on port 9098: Connect failed

Comment: Implies the port is blocked. Possibly by an intermediate network device between you and the server.

Comment: I open port 9098 and also applied Inbound and outbound rule...so why still it refuses to connect

Comment: With public profile in Inbound rule and outbound rule its work..but i want to work it with only Private and Domain profile....

Comment: Like  I said there may be network devices between you and the server interfering. You should investigate that.

Comment: Hi i do it as per pour suggestion, it work for only public profile but I want to it work without public profile(only with private and domain profile) in work-group.

Comment: You should ask a new question to sys Admin type folks. This specific issue is not wcf and my ability to help with that is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same problem

Following config saved my day

Now it did not say time out until 5 min

Server Side

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="meritBasicBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:05:00" enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Merit.Services.Reporting" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="Reporting" binding="netTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="meritEndPointBehaviour" bindingConfiguration="meritBasicBinding" contract="Merit.Services.IReporting"></endpoint>        
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://Localhost:8090/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="meritEndPointBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client Side

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="meritBasicBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" listenBacklog="2147483647"
             closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://Localhost:8090/Reporting" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="meritBasicBinding" behaviorConfiguration="meritEndPointBehaviour" contract="MeritReportingService.IReporting"
    name="NetTcpBinding_IReporting">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/SERVER DOMAIN ADDRESS(usually picked automatically)" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="meritEndPointBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```